# Issue with integrating Spring-boot, Spring-batch, Spring-data-jpa for transaction management

Tags: spring-batch, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot

I am facing issues related to transaction management (especially transaction annotation as requires new) as detailed below:

> 1. I have used Spring-boot (1.1.5.RELEASE) with
>      a. spring-boot-starter-batch
>      b. spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
> 2. Also for this i have used hibernate latest release

My jpa config relevant code is as listed below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xyz.persistence.repository")
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("xyz.persistence.domain");
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

But during execution, I am facing issues related to transaction management.

I have digged dipper in this problem and found of sequence of events as listed below:

> 1. Spring-boot does load my transaction manager as expected
> 2. However after the same, spring-boot loads spring-batch, thereby loading SimpleBatchConfiguration.
> 3. Since SimpleBatchConfiguration have also definition for transaction manager (without @ConditionalOnMissingBean), it overrides my
>      transactionmanager
> 4. Now is turn of spring-data-jpa i.e. JpaBaseConfiguration. This as well as definition of transactionManager, which is almost similar to
>      what i have defined in my jpaconfig. But this does not overrides
>      earlier definition as @ConditionalOnMissingBean is used.

Hence after all the initialization, I am left with transactionmanager injected by Spring-batch which results in transaction manager not working appropriately.

> PS: This was working with spring-boot 0.5.0.m6 (since
>   @ConditionalOnMissingBean was not present in JpaBaseConfiguration)**

I was trying to exclude SimpleBatchConfiguration, but that is also not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Abhay

Comment: Have you tried dropping your manual configuration and opting for `@EnableAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, any resolution for this ?